# Matching and replacing floats with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

Suprisingly, the output of

```
import re
s = "a=2323.232323 b=23.23 c=112  d=12"
pattern = r'a=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) b=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) c=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+)'
tobereplacedwith = r'thisisb=\2 thisisa=\1 thisisc=\3'
print re.sub(pattern, tobereplacedwith, s)
```

is

```
thisisb=2323. thisisa=2323.232323 thisisc=23.23  d=12
```

**Why doesn't this produce**

```
thisisb=23.23 thisisa=2323.232323 thisisc=112  d=12
```

**?**

Comment: Count your groups (i.e., parentheses): you have two sets of parentheses/groups for each of a, b and c. You may need to make some of these non-capturing, or just other referring numbers in your replacement string. Alternatively, use named groups.

Comment: @Evert do you have an example? I couldn't find a way to do it, to make them non-capturing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the perlretut:

> If the groupings in a regexp are nested, $1 gets the group with the
>   leftmost opening parenthesis, $2 the next opening parenthesis, etc.

Source: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Python's regex engine is based on Perl's so the behaviour is similar.

So:

`a=(([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+)` outer capture group i.e. `2323.232323` == Group 1

`a=(([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+)` inner capture group i.e. `(\d*[.])` i.e. `2323.` == Group 2

`b=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+)` outer capture group i.e. `23.23` == Group 3

To get the output you want, try this:

```
import re
s = "a=2323.232323 b=23.23 c=112  d=12"
pattern = r'a=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) b=([-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) c=([-+]?(\d*)([.]\d*)?)'
tobereplacedwith = r'thisisb=\3 thisisa=\1 thisisc=\6'
print re.sub(pattern, tobereplacedwith, s)
```

Output:

```
thisisb=23.23 thisisa=2323.232323 thisisc=112  d=12
```

Comment: I tried with `$1` instead of `\1`, etc. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @JoeYoung. How to get `thisisb=23.23 thisisa=2323.232323 thisisc=112  d=12` as output then?

Answer (score 2):

When your capture groups get complex, sometimes it is easier to used named capture groups. For example:

```
pattern = r'a=(?P<thisisa>[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) b=(?P<thisisb>[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+) c=(?P<thisisc>[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+)'
tobereplacedwith = r'thisisb=\g<thisisb> thisisa=\g<thisisa> thisisc=\g<thisisc>'
```

To create a capture group named `foo`, you use `(?<foo>...)`. To create a back-reference to it, you use `(?=foo)`. To get the contents of it, you use `\g<foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your regex, with the current grouping's:
[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 a=
 (                             # (1 start)
      [-+]? 
      ( \d* [.] )?                  # (2)
      \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \ b=
 (                             # (3 start)
      [-+]? 
      ( \d* [.] )?                  # (4)
      \d+ 
 )                             # (3 end)
 \ c=
 (                             # (5 start)
      [-+]? 
      ( \d* [.] )?                  # (6)
      \d+ 
 )                             # (5 end)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 27 ) 
a=2323.232323 b=23.23 c=112  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 2 , len 11 ) 
2323.232323  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 2 , len 5 ) 
2323.  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 16 , len 5 ) 
23.23  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 16 , len 3 ) 
23.  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 24 , len 3 ) 
112  
 **  Grp 6 -  NULL
```

You don't need the *optional* capture subgroups.
After converting them to *cluster groups* :

```
 # a=([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+) b=([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+) c=([-+]?(?:\d*[.])?\d+)

 a=
 (                             # (1 start)
      [-+]? 
      (?: \d* [.] )?
      \d+ 
 )                             # (1 end)
 \ b=
 (                             # (2 start)
      [-+]? 
      (?: \d* [.] )?
      \d+ 
 )                             # (2 end)
 \ c=
 (                             # (3 start)
      [-+]? 
      (?: \d* [.] )?
      \d+ 
 )                             # (3 end)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 27 ) 
a=2323.232323 b=23.23 c=112  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 2 , len 11 ) 
2323.232323  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 16 , len 5 ) 
23.23  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 24 , len 3 ) 
112
```